# Generating the skeleton of polygon using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, skeleton

I develop a plugin for my project which includes some useful tools. I reviewed some answers in GIS SE about generating skeleton of polygon. I couldn't find any solution which used PyQGIS. HCMGIS plugin has a tool "Skeleton / Medail Axes" but it uses only processing tools.

I want to generate the skeleton of a polygon using pure PyQGIS without using Processing tools. After doing some digging I found [`voronoiDiagram`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.0/core/Geometry/QgsGeometry.html#qgis.core.QgsGeometry.voronoiDiagram) method defined in `QgsGeometry`. I don't figure it out how to use it correctly.

I used `voronoiDiagram` in the following script, but it throws an exception: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'disjoint'`.

What am I doing wrong? How can I improve/change this code to get skeleton of polygon?

My code is:

```
# get polygon layer
polygonLyr = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("polygons")[0]

# create new layer
centerlineLyr =  QgsVectorLayer("Linestring?crs=EPSG:3857", "Centerlines", "memory")
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(centerlineLyr)

# layer has one polygon
polygonGeom = list(polygonLyr.getFeatures())[0].geometry()

# create voronoi lines
lineCollection = polygonGeom.voronoiDiagram(edgesOnly=True).asMultiPolyline()

#select lines and add them to layer
centerlineLyr.startEditing()
for line in lineCollection:
    if not line.disjoint(polygonGeom):
        f = QgsFeature()
        f.setGeometry(line)
        centerlineLyr.addFeature(f)
centerlineLyr.commitChanges()
```

Comment: If you `print(type(lineCollection))`, it sends you back `<class 'list'>`

Comment: @VincentBré `lineCollection` is a list. I know that. The problem is items in the list.   Each item of  `lineCollection` is a list, too. I would expected that each item is a line.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've added a script and some explanation about it.

1. You need polygon boundary for testing if voronoi line intersects boundary.
2. You need densified geometry. Because if polygon boundary has a long segment, skeleton will not be as desired (see the image). Densified geometry is just for generating voronoi lines. I used 10 meter. Depending on your data, you may need to change the value.

[image]

3. `voronoiDiagram` returns `QgsGeometry`. You have to convert it into geometry list for iterating over it. Since the result is a `MultiLineString` type, you need to use `asGeometryCollection` instead of `asMultiPolyline`. **The reason of getting error** is that `asMultiPolyline` returns list of list of `QgsPointXY`. But `asGeometryCollection` returns list of `QgsGeometry` (in this case list of `LineGeometry`)
4. If a line in `geom_coll` doesn't intersect polygon boundary and it is not outside polygon, that line is a part of skeleton.
5. After detecting lines of skeleton, convert separate lines into multiline. (You can add lines to layer as separate line features, if you want. I preferred multiline)

```py
skeleton_layer =  QgsVectorLayer("Linestring?crs=EPSG:3857", "Skeleton", "memory")
polygon_layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("polygons")[0]

for feature in polygon_layer.getFeatures():
    poly_geom = feature.geometry()    
    # (1)
    boundary = poly_geom.convertToType(1) # polygon boundary    
    # (2)
    dens_geom = poly_geom.densifyByDistance(10) # densified geometry     
    # (3) voronoi line collection 
    geom_coll = dens_geom.voronoiDiagram(edgesOnly=True).asGeometryCollection()    
    # (4) line collection for skeleton
    line_coll = [line.convertToType(1).asPolyline() for line in geom_coll \
            if not line.intersects(boundary) and not line.disjoint(poly_geom)]

    # (5) convert individual lines into multiline 
    m = QgsGeometry.fromMultiPolylineXY(line_coll)
    f = QgsFeature()
    f.setGeometry(m)
    skeleton_layer.dataProvider().addFeatures([f])

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(skeleton_layer)
```

[image]