# Generating transects to the extent of a polygon

Tags: postgis, arcgis-pro, line, transects

I am trying to clip pavement polygons in Arc Pro (but will use postgis or other software), and I'm using transects to do this. My method is:

- Generate the centreline of the polygon
- Use the Generate Transects Along Lines to generate transects

The issue is that the transects are a set length, and there are areas of the pavement larger than others. However, if I increase the length of the transects, this is causing duplication of transects at other points in the network. I realise I can explode these lines, but I do not want the lines so close together.

[image]

Is there a way to generate transects where you are able to specify the length of the transect to be the extent of a polygon, rather than a set length? This does not have to be in Arc and I'm open to other software.

Comment: Decide which software you want to use to solve this or your question is probably going to get closed.

Comment: It would preferably be in ArcPro.

Comment: Does [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/425479/128665) help at all? It is for QGIS but the principle remains the same and can be transferred to ArcGIS. Of course, your objective is not to find the width of the polygon, so the last part can be skipped.