# Creating middle line between two lines in QGIS

Tags: qgis, line, polygon-creation

I'm looking for a way or tool in QGIS that could create a mean line between two line features, from a line shapefile (not a polygon). See sketch image below for clarification.

[image]

Comment: Alright updated for QGIS only

Comment: In PostGIS, you could creata a central axis https://postgis.net/docs/ST_ApproximateMedialAxis.html or skeleton https://postgis.net/docs/ST_StraightSkeleton.html

Comment: Can you build polygons from your lines, then create a center line from that such as discussed here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/423137/creating-centre-line-of-odd-shaped-polygon-in-qgis.  If not I came across this which includes a method using Voroni tesseation that might work for you: https://www.reddit.com/r/gis/comments/siuaoo/how_to_get_a_line_through_middle_of_two_lines/

Comment: @John, when I create a polygon it comes out very jagged and not suitable for my goal. Thank you for those other suggestions they look very interesting, I will definitely check them out!

I managed to get a solution by creating a polygon by hand/editing a then with the Skeleton function similar Babel mentioned above. But there must be an easier solution out there..

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/318721/creating-centerline-of-river-in-qgis

Comment: @BERA that one refers to https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33887/finding-centrelines-from-polygons-in-qgis

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Generic/algorithmic description

On one of the lines, create points in a regular interval. Connect these points to the closest point of the other line by creating a line. Get the centroid of these lines. Now connect the centroids to a line and you're done.

#### Implementation

Run the mentioned tools from `Menu Processing > Toolbox`:

1. Select one of the lines and run [Points along geometry](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#points-along-geometry) and be sure to check the box `Selected features only`.
2. On the created point layer, run [Geometry by expression](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#geometry-by-expression) with this expression:

   ```
    centroid(
        make_line (
            $geometry, 
            closest_point (
                overlay_nearest ('line', $geometry, limit:=2)[1],  -- replace `line` with the name of your line layer
                $geometry
            )
        )
    )
   ```
3. Run [Points to path](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorcreation.html#qgispointstopath) to connect the points from step 2.

*Blue points: step 1; red points: step 2; red line: step 3:*
[image]

Comment: Thank you Babel, this is indeed a useful solution!